# Image as icon appearance

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsimage, nsbutton, nstoolbar

A am experiencing a toolbar design issue.
A toolbar button with a "sidebar" image in a native Apple application looks like this:

[image]

I made three attempts to re-create the same appearance in `.xib` file:

[image]]

The first button includes scaled a 200px by 200px PDF image from resource assets. The result icon is blurry and oversized.

The second button creates image from `NSImage.touchBarSidebarTemplateName` with scaling:

```
        let sidebarImage = NSImage(named: NSImage.touchBarSidebarTemplateName)
        sidebarImage?.size = NSSize(width: 16, height: 22)
        showHideSidebarToolbarButton.image = sidebarImage
```

The second attempt is the most successful one.

The last attempt - is the native `NSImage.touchBarSidebarTemplateName` without any custom programming scaling. The result is the most blurry and deformed one.

What is the trick? Does it mean, one should re-create all the icon images by themself? Is there any chance to drop-in system image in a button without any future adjustments?

Comment: Any info in the documentation of `touchBarSidebarTemplateName`? Is the button a `NSButton` or a `NSToolbarItem`? How is the button created? What is the setting of "Style" and "Scaling"? What is the default size of the image? What is the size of the button?